# Comparing cardinalities of different sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to compare cardinalities of all the sets that I can think of.

So far, I have

$|\{0,1\}| < |\mathcal{P}(\{0,1\})| < |\mathbb{N}|$

$|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}^2| = |\mathbb{Z}| =|\mathbb{Z}^2| = |\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{Q}^2|$

$|\mathbb{Q}^2| < |\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}^2| = |(0,1)| = |(0,1) \times (0,1)| = |[0,100]|$

$|[0,100]| < 2^{|\mathbb{R}|} < |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$

I am a bit unsure with some of the inequalites and especially the last part

$2^{|\mathbb{R}|} < |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$

Is what I have correct?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right, except for the inequality you are unsure of.

Indeed $2^{|\mathbb{R}|} = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$, since $2^{|\mathbb{R}|} = |\{ f : \mathbb{R} \to 2\}|$. Here $2 = \{0,1\}$ is the standard definition of 2 as a set.

Of course, we can biject 
$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ with functions
from $\mathbb{R} \to 2$ by

$$
(A \subseteq \mathbb{R}) 
\mapsto 
f(r) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & r \not \in A\\ 1 & r \in A 
\end{cases}
$$

with inverse

$$
(f : \mathbb{R} \to 2) \mapsto \{ r ~|~ f(R) = 1\}
$$

So $2^{|\mathbb{R}|} = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer so that other users know where to spend their time ^_^